# In Python, how to get the sum and average while in a loop

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, sum, average

I've managed to implement a loop but keep getting a syntax error when I try the `sum` function. I need the numbers input by the user to be totalled and the average given as well. This has to be outputted to the user. Could you please guide me on where to go from here, thank you.
This is what I've done so far:

```
while 1:
    NumCalc = input ("Enter Number :")
    if NumCalc == "done": break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you can do if you want to compute the sum and the mean **after** the loop ends:

```
nums = []
while 1:
    NumCalc = input ("Enter Number:")
    if NumCalc == "done": break
    nums.append(float(NumCalc))

print('Sum:', sum(nums), 'and average:', sum(nums)/len(nums))
```

---

**While** in a loop:

```
s = 0.0
counter = 0

while 1:
    NumCalc = input("Enter Number: ")
    if NumCalc == "done":
        break

    NumCalc = float(NumCalc)
    s += NumCalc
    counter += 1


    print('Sum is', s, 'and the mean is', s/counter)
```

Output:

```
Enter Number: 5
Sum is 5.0 and the mean is 5.0
Enter Number: 2
Sum is 7.0 and the mean is 3.5
Enter Number: 4
Sum is 11.0 and the mean is 3.66666666667
Enter Number: 6
Sum is 17.0 and the mean is 4.25
Enter Number: 2
Sum is 19.0 and the mean is 3.8
```

Comment: appreciate the help but it does not work this is the output I am receiving any idea why?Enter Number: 5
Sum is:
Enter Number: 6
Sum is:
Enter Number: done
>>>

Comment: @user3417793 what's your Python version?

Comment: if it helps this is how the output is supposed to look so ive been told ####Enter value 1:5
Enter value 1:8
Enter value 1:11
Enter value 1:done
Thank you.
Sum: 24  Average: 8.0

Comment: @user3417793 My bad. Thought you were using Python2. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
sum = 0
while 1:
    i += 1
    NumCalc = input ("Enter Number :")
    if NumCalc == "done": break
    sum = sum + NumCalc
    print "Average is ", sum/i
```